# Google Maps API Error for max requests per day/second

Tags: php, google-maps, google-api

I'm building out a class to work with the google maps geocode api. The documentation states that there is a daily (2500 free, 100,000 business) and per second (5 free, 10 business) request max. I've done lots of googling and looking at other posts on this and my question that I can't seem to answer is this:

For those who have implemented this to a point to where they use it or can test it, how do I tell if an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error is related to the DAILY max or the PER SECOND max? How do I distinguish between the two? I can't seem to find the answer in the documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't distinguish from the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT itself.  You can test to determine whether it's the daily or per second max by waiting a period of time and trying again.  This is what [Google says](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits) to do in order to distinguish between the two types of errors.

> Upon receiving a response with status code OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, your application should determine which usage limit has been exceeded. This can be done by pausing for 2 seconds and resending the same request. If status code is still OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, your application is sending too many requests per day. Otherwise, your application is sending too many requests per second.

Answer (score 0):

[Google advises](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits) to pause the script for two seconds and try it again. Based on the result of the resent query, your application can differ between the daily or the per seconds limit.